# Does silent updates also upgrade to the latest distribution?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, updates

I enabled silent updates for all my repositories and wondering if this would also automatically silently upgrade my Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04 when the upgrade is available in April?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it will automatically update, however you can be notified about any new Ubuntu versions (which I think is what happens by default):

Go to > System Settings > Software Sources > Updates

Near the bottom it says "Notify me of a new Ubuntu Version", and you have 3 options:

- Never
- For long-term support versions
- For any new version

Comment: BullfrogBlues is right. It will never do a `do-release-upgrade` to another release. The automatic upgrades will only keep your packages up-to-date in the current release scope.